# Spring Boot Rest call - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have a war file with spring boot as server side and angular 8 as front end.

and the war is getting deployed in remote machine where ip changes on restart.

If I deploy the war where rest request call from  angular are made with ip address of the host it was working fine

```
http://54.172.42.170:8080/test/getMessage
```

since the IP is changing on each time machine restart i need to change the code each time

Is there a way where i can make the rest call with out referring ip address, as both angular and spring boot are packaged in same war

i tried using local host in the rest url , but getting error

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

it was working only when war is deployed in my desktop not on remote machine, which makes sense.

Adding Client Code:

```
    public SERVER_IP:string="54.172.42.170"; 
    public SERVER_PORT:string="8080";
    public SERVER_PROTOCOL:string="http";
    public APP_CONTEXT:string="test";
    public  URL_BASE:string= this.SERVER_PROTOCOL+"://"+this.SERVER_IP+":"+this.SERVER_PORT+"/"+  this.APP_CONTEXT+"/";
    public  URL_GET_MESSAGE:string= this.URL_BASE +"getMessage"; 

    this.http.get(this.constant.URL_GET_MESSAGE,{params: data})
```

Comment: can you post your client code? How you're making call? You can possibly do relative URL.

Comment: It's related to network configuration either you can bind your instance to 127.0.0.1 or use static IP so that your ip won't change every time you restart you machine. Configure your tomcat to bind to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a pretty simple way to implement this. When you build your application, set your SERVER_IP parameter to "/". This simple forward slash means that if your angular application loads on xyz.com then your API url will be xyz.com.

Also you can then form the URL using the code:

```
public  URL_BASE:string= "/"+  this.APP_CONTEXT+"/";
```

Of course, you'll need to get rid of Port by using a reverse proxy like NGINX.

Thus, it will always be relative to your current host URL. This is an approach we use in multiple of our applications and it works smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Either u fixed the remote machine ip permanently neither you will do the testing in your local machine it will work.